# Why can't I do "import sys.argv[1]"?

Tags: python, argv, sys

I created a module called parameter.py and wanted to import it using sys.argv as shown below.

```
import sys
from sys.argv[1] import *
```

But when I run the python file I get the following error:

```
python test.py parameter


File "test.py", line 17
    from sys.argv[1] import *
                 ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why doesn't it work and what else can I do to make it work?

Comment: "a module called parameter.py that I created using sys.argv" What exactly do you think this means? How do you believe you are "creating" modules "using sys.argv", and why do you think `parameter.py` is such a module? (Please be sure to distinguish the *module name* from the *file name*.)

Comment: If names in `import` statements would be evaluated as expressions, then `import foo` would mean “import the module with the name that variable `foo` contains”, not “import module foo”…

Comment: It's also completely unclear what *problem you hope to solve* by doing this. If you don't know ahead of time which module will be imported, how do you know that importing it is a good idea?

Comment: Anyway, the syntax doesn't make any sense for the same reason that `'parameter' = 3` doesn't make any sense. Strings are not the same as identifiers.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I meant to say I created a module that I want to import using sys.argv. I edited my question to be more clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Variables** are not allowed in **import** statement

```
import sys
__import__(sys.argv[1])
```

**Global Import**

```
import sys
globals().update(__import__(sys.argv[1]).__dict__)
```

**Example Usage**

```
import sys

sys.argv.append("math")
pi = __import__(sys.argv[-1]).pi
print(pi)
```

**Or**

```
import sys

sys.argv.append("math")
globals().update({k: v for k, v in __import__(sys.argv[-1]).__dict__.items() if not k.startswith("__")})
print(pi)
print(__name__)
```

**Output**

```
3.141592653589793
__main__
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I tried both out and seems like the globals method does import it correctly (exactly what I wanted!) except that `__name__` is now also switched to the name of the module I have imported. If I were to import the module using `from module import *`, the `__name__` remains as `__main__`. 
What's the difference here? And is there a way I could import using sys.argv (like it did with globals()) while keeping `__name__` as `__main__`?

Comment: @monosix Sorry for forgetting to exclude members like `__name__`, `__doc__`, `__package__`, `__loader__`, `__spec__`. I've changed the answer now.